# C#: How can I import multiple CSV files into my DataGridView and if they match only the price will go into a new column?

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I am looking for a solution and was hoping any of you guys can help me with this. I have 3 CSV files with a product code and a price. After I imported the first CSV file I want the program to see the duplicate product codes and only put the price of that product code next to the other price of the previous CSV file.

Images will probably make it more clear about what I am talking about.

Example of what a CSV file looks like:
[image: Example of what a CSV file looks like]

After 1 csv import:
[image: After 1 csv import]

With 3 csv imports
[image: With 3 csv imports]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! What have you tried so far?
Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to create the CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help you if we can't see any code. I tried to come up with something. It may help you to get an idea how it could work.

The .csv you are using has different values for the price. Sometimes it is:
**x,yz** and sometimes you got **x.yz**. I would recommend to use '.' because you can directly parse it into a float (price). As well delete the € out of the price value. A price in a database or in other data files like a .csv should not be a string. If you decide to leave it just remove the first char with:

```
yourString.Remove(0,1);
```

First of all here some info about the files and locations I have:

```
    string path = @"C:\__ER2S3_Abteilung\StackOverFlow\Data_product_price\";
    string[] files = new string[]
    {
        "first_list.csv",
        "second_list.csv",
        "third_list.csv"
    };
```

I created a class that looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public float? FirstPrice { get; set; } = null;
    public float? SecondPrice { get; set; } = null;
    public float? ThirdPrice { get; set; } = null;
    public float AvgPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I created a list that will save all the products you read.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

Then read files and add all the products, but check if the products already exist in the list when adding them:

```
        foreach(string item in files)
        {
            string fullpath = path + item;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    try
                    {
                        float.Parse(line.Split('|')[1]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    string productname = line.Split('|')[0];
                    float price = float.Parse(line.Split('|')[1]);
                    if (!products.Exists(e => e.ProductCode == productname))
                    {
                        products.Add(new Product() { ProductCode = productname , FirstPrice = price });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach(Product _product in products)
                        {
                            if(_product.ProductCode == productname)
                            {
                                if(_product.SecondPrice == null)
                                {
                                    _product.SecondPrice = price;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    _product.ThirdPrice = price;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Bind the list of products to your DataGridview. The columns of the DataGridView are the properties in the object Product. 
For average calculation add following:

```
foreach(Product product in products)
{
     product.AvgPrice = (float)((product.FirstPrice + product.SecondPrice + product.ThirdPrice) / 3);
}
```

Don't forget to add the INotifyPorpertyChanged interface and use that. This will auto update changes made to the list automatically in your UI.

It is not the most beautiful way but it works.

I tested it. I get a list of Products with all the values from the different .csv files. And the calculated AvgValue.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for your comment. Could not have come up with something like this myself. Only thing is that I never used lists. How do I get the list into my Datagridview?

Comment: No problem, I can edit the answer and show you how to add that too. Are you using wpf or winforms?

Comment: Can you add the winforms datagridview code in your question? if you don't Ill just create something by myself tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean with the datagridview code? Using Visual Studio you can just drop the datagridview using the toolbox. I just can't figure out how to get the list into the datatable, because the list contains multiple classes. Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: So you want to display it AND put it into the database?
And I'll try to come up with something that should help you with the datagridview. Just need a little time for that.¨¨

Comment: No, I wasn't clear sorry. I just want the list displayed into a datagridview.